# How to unit test the following scenario?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following method

```
    public override void SendSync(int frame, byte[] syncData)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(4 + syncData.Length))
        {
            ms.WriteArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(frame));
            ms.WriteArray(syncData);

            queuedSyncPackets.Add(ms.GetBuffer());
        }
    }
```

and I would like to unit test it to guarantee 2 things:

1. <strike>The `ms` is disposed at the end</strike> ok will use roslyn
2. `4 + syncData.Length` is equal to `ms.GetBuffer().Capacity` right at `queuedSyncPackets.Add(ms.GetBuffer());`

How can I do that?

Comment: There is no need to unit test the `using` statement and the capacity, Microsoft has done this for you.

Comment: As a general rule, do not unit test code owned by external dependencies (particularly when it is guaranteed by the compiler).  Unit testing specifically focuses on functionality within your _own_ code.

Comment: im interested on blocking any further developers from removing it. Its the Nth time I re-instate that damn using

Comment: Don't write a test.  Use Roslyn Analyzers and a good .editorconfig that flags warnings or errors when something isn't properly disposed of.  Testing proves functionality.  Analyzers enforce styling consistency, which is exactly what this is.

Comment: @DavidL got it! good point!

Comment: Is there some sort of observable side effect that happens when case number 2 does not occur? If so, you could verify in a test that that side effect doesn't happen

Comment: @devNull if n2 doesn't add up, I have a "memory leak"... the memory will actually be reclaimed but the extra allocation will cause GC to run more frequently, and the user will feel extra "lags"

Comment: _im interested on blocking any further developers from removing it_ - alternative approach to trust further developers that they know what they doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Philosophical part:

You really should not be unit testing how method is implemented inside. You should test that it behaves correctly but should not demand particular implementation. In this case it would be more clear to implement method with just new array and two Copy operations instead of using MemoryStream - demanding that method creates and dispose memory stream or uses particular byte array is likely wrong. Indeed if you would expect some particular caching/pooling to be used you can assert that.

The ms is disposed at the end:

Testing presence of `using` on `MemoryStream` usage - since `MemoryStream` has no unmanaged components there is absolutely nothing going to change if you have one or not with code shown (`Dispose` will prevent future read/write operations which may imact other usage patterns). So as result this particular case is pretty much style preference and should be caught by code analyzers or code review.

If you really want to test that - one option would be to move creation of the stream to a factory method and capture that created stream for later verification. Something like

```
 public override void SendSync(
       int frame, byte[] syncData, Func<MemoryStream> streamFactory)
 {
       using (var ms = streamFactory())...
 }

 ...MyTest()
 {
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    SendSync(..., ()=>ms);
    Assert.IsFalse(ms.CanRead, 
       "Expecting stream to be disposed and hence no more readable");
 }
```

Note: as mentioned in comments and the question it is probably overkill for this particular case to test that stream was disposed. If someone removes it as not necessary and someone else adds it back as "required by our coding standard" this can't be solved with unit tests - talk to people instead.

Check parameters to a method:

Assuming `queuedSyncPackets` is an injected dependency you just need to add check at the moment of the call that data is expected. Usually done with some mocking framework like `moq`, but you can just implement you own class that simply checks the array size in that call.

Note that code shown in the post will succeed the check but it does not have to (as that part of behavior is not documented). `GetBuffer()` returns *internal array* of the MemoryStream and its size is same or bigger than resulting data but is not guaranteed to not grow stream when there is no space left. If you must use `GetBuffer()` that you have to pass size of the stream too.

Approximate sample for the test using moq:

```
byte[] theBuffer = null;
mockQueuedSyncPackets.Setup(c => c.Add(It.IsAny<byte[]>()))
        .Callback<byte[]>((obj) => theBuffer = obj);
var theSender = new Sender(mockQueuedSyncPackets.Object);
theSender.SendSync(123, syncData);
Assert.AreEqual(4 + syncData.Length, theBuffer.Length);
```